# IllegalStateException on enable persistence in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After the new section of failures and ANRs collected from `Android Vitals`, I'm having several `IllegalStateException` with `firebase database` on enable `persistence`.

```
public class Configuration extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnable(true);
        } 
    }

}
```

Exceptions:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:0)
  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseDatabase.java:0)
  at <OR>.getInstance(FirebaseDatabase.java:0)
  at <OR>.setPersistenceEnabled(FirebaseDatabase.java:0)
  at <OR>.zziE(FirebaseDatabase.java:0)
  at myapp.MyActivity.<init>(MyActivity.java:0)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:0)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
```

---

**Update 02/03/2018**

According to the suggestion of @Frank van Puffelen I created this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47521133/6744062), but the problem still appears.

[image]

Today, 9:14 AM on app version 27
LGE LG K8 (mm1v), 1536MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 1

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:      
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2339)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)     
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)     
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5551)     
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)     
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:731)     
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:621)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:      
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance (FirebaseApp.java)     
  at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance (FirebaseDatabase.java)
  or                     .setPersistenceEnabled (FirebaseDatabase.java)
  or                     .zzph (FirebaseDatabase.java)     
  at myapp.MyActivity.<init> (MyActivity.java)     
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java)     
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1068)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2329)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)     
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)     
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)     
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5551)     
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)     
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:731) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:621)
```

Comment: See [Firebase database Persistence not working #15](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/15)

Comment: Search your code for other calls to `setPersistenceEnable()`.  If the crash was the result of the call in `Configuration.onCreate()`, I would expect to see lines in the stack trace related to application creation,  for example  `android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate`.  Instead there are lines suggesting the system is trying to create an instance of `MyActivity`.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K - I have removed the code from the application class and used the proposed code for the solution, but it did not solve the problem, it still generates the error logs.

Comment: @Bob Snyder - As Frank van Puffelen quoted, the error is due to my application being multi-process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FirebaseContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        if (mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
 ... >
    <provider
         android:name=".test.FirebaseContentProvider"
         android:authorities="com.test.FirebaseContentProvider"
         android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the code below:

```
private static boolean calledAlready = false;
if (!calledAlready) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    calledAlready = true;
}
```

You need to use this code, as the first code from your `onCreate` method. In this case, `setPersistenceEnabled()` method will only be called if it wasn't called before, due the presence of `calledAlready` boolean.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Most likely the problem is caused by a multi-process app, which is what @ ρяσѕρєя K linked to. In that cases this code won't help, since the static boolean is linked to a single process instance. Content providers are the only proper solution for this, aside from simply calling `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` in your main activity (which means it gets called multiple times, but that doesn't matter).